# How to get `ReturnsNotZero` in CFEngine?

Tags: cfengine

There's `ReturnsZero` function in `CFEngine` but there's no `ReturnsNotZero`.

If I do need to define a class depending on non-zero return value of a command, what should I do?

Examples in `CFEngine2` is preferred but `CFEngine3` is fine :-)

---

**Example for `CFEngine2`**

( which I don't think it can be found in any official document. It takes me about half an hour to find this trick in `CFEngine2`'s source code )

```
classes:
    has_python27 = ( ReturnsZero(/usr/bin/which python27) )
    no_python27 = ( !ReturnsZero(/usr/bin/which python27) )
```

Hope this helps someone with lagacy `CFEngine`

**Example for `CFEngine3`**

Please read zzamboni's answer below :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With CFEngine 3, you can simply use `not` on the result from `returnszero()`:

```
classes:
    "someclass" not => returnszero("/some/command");
```